# Variable evaluation for Path does not work in jmeter, how can I debug?

Tags: jmeter

#### I have a simple Test Plan that uses some variables.

[image]

#### Some of them are extracted from page result like `CSRF_TOKEN` and `REG`.

[image]
[image]

#### I try to use `REG` variable as part of `PATH` for "Register" http request.

[image]

#### In *Debug Sampler* I can see that `REG` got set.

[image]

#### But the *Register* HTTP Request is not evaluating it.

[image]

#### I am out of ideas why.

- Using `${EVENT_NAME}` for Tickets Page works fine. `EVENT_NAME` is configured on *Test Plan* level as defined variable.
- Using `${CSRF_TOKEN}` works as request parameter, works as header parameter (in Header Manager) as well.
- In the *Provide details* using variables in `PATH` works again.
- How is it possible to debug why it does not work for *Register* request?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out I made a mistake when defining a value for post http request parameter in *Register* step. I incorrectly called `__RandomString` function (wrong syntax).

This failed deeply inside JMetric without any error and probably stopped it from processing subsequent expanding of variables.

After fixing my code to use `${__RandomString(20, 1234567890poiuytrewqasdfghjklmnbvcx, EMAIL)}@example.com` it started behave normally again.